# Как вывести предсказания модели нейронной сети?

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, keras, искусственный-интеллект

Я делаю следующее:

```
a = model.predict(["3", "24.14", "-10.5", "2023-09-18", "10:24:14", '25.74', "3.49049"])
print(a)
```

И я ожидаю, что модель выведет время в минутах, вроде:`7.8343`, но происходит следующее:

```
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 39ms/step
array([b'3', b'24.14', b'-10.5', b'2023-09-18', b'10:24:14', b'25.74',
       b'3.49049'], dtype=object)
```

Я использую эту модель для обучения

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(5, activation="elu", input_shape=(5, 1)))
model.add(LSTM(30, activation="relu", input_shape=(5,)))
model.add(Dense(1, input_shape=(30,)))
```

Я использую библиотеку `keras`

Подскажите, как мне вывести предсказания модели

Comment: Вы бы добавили информацию, что за библиотеки используете. Что у вас является входными данными для предсказания... т.е. у вас это судя по всему лист из 7 параметров, так?

Answer (score 0):

Конечно, мы вообще не знаем, что у вас за модель. Но судя по тому, что она возвращает, она копирует входные данные и добавляет в конце предсказание. Таким образом, результат работы модели можно получить, взяв последний элемент возвращаемого ей массива. А, и ещё она возвращает байтовое представление строк, чтобы получить из байт строку её нужно декодировать.

```py
result = a[-1].decode()
print(result)
# 7.8343
```

Comment: Прошу прощения, я не правильно указал данные которые выводит модель. Взгляните пожалуйста на них еще раз. Прошу прощение за это

Comment: У вас такое ощущение, что в итоге выводится массив из тех же значений, но с индексом b. Лучше вам привести код, какие библиотеки, что вы хотите получить вы уже сказали.

Comment: Так и есть. Поэтому и пишу об этой проблеме

Comment: @Volk Добрый день. Подскажите пожалуйста с моей ошибкой. Если вас не затруднит

Comment: Может приложить полный код, я не специалист по Keras поэтому надо посмотреть внимательно шаги, которые вы выполнили для обучения модели, там очень важна последовательность.